# Ubuntu 13.04 won't recognize my bootable USB

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04 on my ASUS F201E laptop. I'm trying to install a new OS that is meant to be more compatible with my harware.

I've already created a bootable USB with the new OS on it no problem, and am now trying to reboot and install this new OS on my laptop.

My USB is recognized in the BIOS,(I can access the USB 'specs' in BIOS) however not in the boot preference options... It won't boot.

I've played around with other BIOS settings, nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"I'm trying to install Mint"* <-- I'm sorry, but that makes it quite off-topic here, I'm afraid. Mint is not Ubuntu.

Comment: *"I asked this same question about a day ago"* <-- We don't re-ask questions here. Please edit/improve your previous question instead. http://askubuntu.com/q/359508/88802

Comment: I asked it from a different perspective, trying to improve it.

Comment: You ought to have edited the existing question. That's how we do it. Don't worry, that would bring it to the top of the list, so it wouldn't go unnoticed.

Comment: "`I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04`" ... in 2109, six years later ?!

Comment: Btw, while your question is certainly on-topic here, you might in future want to be aware of our [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to boot via UEFI and your .iso doesn't support it. Make sure you know how you want to install your OS (UEFI or legacy aka BIOS). Check if your Laptop supports UEFI. Look inside your BIOS-Settings for an UEFI or CSM setting...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the bootable USB will not show in the GRUB menu, but it will just boot before GRUB loads. Something is wrong with the bootable USB. How did you create it?

I would use dd. It's a command line based utility that, among other things, can create a bootable USB stick.

So download the Mint image to, say, your Downloads folder, insert the USB stick and open a terminal.
The steps are as follow:

```
$ cd Downloads
$ lsblk
```

The output shall be something like this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    42G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 242,1G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  48,8G  0 part /home
├─sda6   8:6    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0 124,7G  0 part /media/data
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sdb      8:16   0 465,7G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465,7G  0 part
```

Try to spot out which the USB drive is. You will easily recognize it based on the SIZE column. Please note that you need to spot out the USB stick and not any of its partitions (that is, the ones with TYPE = part). If any of the partitions of the USB stick are mounted, first unmount them all by typing for each of them:

```
$ sudo umount MOUNTPOINT
```

Then write the iso image to the USB stick (**ALL THE DATA IN THE USB STICK WILL BE DESTROYED**):

```
sudo dd if=<mint_iso_image> of=/dev/sdX
```

where **X** is the letter that corresponds to the USB stick and should definitely not be "a".

***Disclaimer:*** Please note that if you are not sure which is your USB stick (or pick a wrong one), this process may have disastrous effects (ie. destroy your data on your hard disk). **Please proceed with caution!**

Regards, Errikos.

Comment: Hi Errikos, Thanks! I'm in the process of doing that now. I just want to check a few things. I'll paste a copy of the readout from my terminal. Am I right in thinking my USB is sdb, with 7.5G in size? I think so... Also, the image I downloaded reads like this : linuxmint-13-mate-dvd-32bit.iso  Does that look about right? The icon is a picture of a cd. I only ask because a friend of mine downloaded this version onto my usb stick and it took about two hours. Thanks for your help, much appreciated. I just want to check these things before I continue with it!

Comment: sdb                              8:16   0   7,5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                           8:17   0   7,5G  0 part  /media/sarah/C412-7B5C

Comment: I didn't have room to include the whole readout, but I only have the sda and sdb... the usb is 8G and has about 7.5G free space.

Comment: Yes, that must be your USB stick. But you first need to unmount the sdb1 partition: `sudo umount  /media/sarah/C412-7B5C`. Then cd to the directory where the image lies and `sudo dd if=./linuxmint-13-mate-dvd-32bit.iso of=/dev/sdb`. How did he "download" the image onto the USB stick? Copy-paste like? That is definitely not how you create a bootable USB stick.

Comment: No he made the USB bootable and then downloaded the mint version from the website. It took about a second for me to download the image to my computer.. does that sound right?

Comment: Not really. Try `md5sum linuxmint-13-mate-dvd-32bit.iso`. If the result is `43ca0be4501b9d1a46fea25ec2cd556e`, then it is OK, if not, you will need to re-download (most likely).

Comment: Ah and it didn't unmount, though I used what you wrote: sarah@sarah-X201EP:~$ sudo umount /media/sarah/C412-7B5C

Comment: Actually it may have, does this look right? : sdb                              8:16   0   7,5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                           8:17   0   7,5G  0 part

Comment: Yes, it has been unmounted.

Comment: Ok. When you say "cd to the directory where the image lies" what do you mean? (Thanks for spending the time to help btw!)

Comment: cd stands for "change directory". If you downloaded the iso to the Downloads folder (most likely) you need to run `cd Downloads`.

Comment: Great. I checked the md5sum command and it matched what you had above (43ca etc). So I put in the sudo dd command and it's still working, just taking a looong time...

Comment: It's normal, it has to write the entire iso image to the USB stick.

Comment: 1839104+0 records in
1839104+0 records out
941621248 bytes (942 MB) copied, 264,76 s, 3,6 MB/s
   Yes? Can I try to boot it now?

Comment: Yes, you can. Make sure you select the USB drive to boot from the BIOS.

Comment: Ah great. Thanks so much, will give it a try now. Will let you know!

Comment: Ah I'm afraid it's not even recognizing the usb now... not on my desktop and not in the BIOS...

Comment: Do I need to remount it in terminal or something?

Comment: On your desktop it's normal. However, it should recognize it in the BIOS.

Comment: It's not. I'll have another go but it just wasn't there... any ideas?

Comment: The BIOS recognize the Flash Drive and let me open this ("open easyFlash utility") Here my USB shows FSO and O EFI <DIR> .  My fast boot is disabled, my launch CSM is disabled. The only boot option that shows is my normal Ubuntu. There is an Add New Boot option, and when I open it, I'm asked for a pathway and I don't know how to write a pathway to my USB. My SATA mode selection is IDE (I changed this, can always change it back if need be. Serial ATA port 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said , " I've played around with other BIOS settings " , i assume that you have configured the correct boot order in BIOS.

The pendrive wasn't bootable.U can easily create a bootable pendrive with the help of a utility named [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

To install  Unetbootin , go to terminal & type :

> sudo apt-get install unetbootin

after you are done with the installation , type :

> unetbootin

to launch unetbootin.

Select the image file , pendrive and press ok.If you have plugged in only one pendrive to your system , Unetbootin will automatically detect the pendrive and will save much hastle for you.Once the setup is over, you are good to go.

[image]

[image]